# Apache Camel - Skip footer / last line

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using apache camel in a routing context to integrate some CSV files. If I want to skip the first line of the csv I can easily do it in the unmarshal:

```
<unmarshal>
            <csv delimiter=";" skipFirstLine="true"/>
</unmarshal>
```

My question is, whats the best way to ignore/skip the last line of the file ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Camel CSV component (ver. 2.18.1) does not support skipping the footer out of the box. In case you can keep the whole file in memory I would advice to use a Camel processor to remove the last line before unmarshalling.

There is also a similar question answered by Claus Ibsen for the Bindy Component: [Camel CSVRecord Camel Bindy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425595/camel-csvrecord-camel-bindy)

Answer (score 0):

The last line can not be skipped. Please read the file from the end and remove the last line using a File Reader